# Apache BaseNCodec how to encode string

Tags: java, apache, encoding

I need to encode some strings in my Java program using BaseN encoding (similar to Base64, but we want to use different base for encoding for different strings) and I found that it could be possible with Apache's library BaseNCodec. I found and included that into my project, but I cannot make it work.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.html

It says there that this is abstract class, but I cannot extend it, I always get errors like "Inherited abstract methods are not accessible" in NetBeans. Is there any examples on this, how to use this library in a proper way?

Comment: Any progress in this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the `BaseNCodec` class (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.html) is not `final` which means that it can be inherited. Perhaps there were some fault during the steps when you tried to inherit, do you have a pointer to your source code?

Worst case scenario is that you can migrate the source file into your own code base since it's open source.

To derive a not "regular" codec you can take a look at the two implementation what Apache commons have: Base64 (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) and Base32 (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32.html). Unfortunately it seems that this won't be as simple as just defining a custom encoding (`ENCODE_TABLE`) and decoding table (`DECODE_TABLE`). There's fair enough logic revolving around for example how the fractional bits are treated across the dictionary letters and also at the end of the bit stream.